# how to do VerneMQ cluster with 3 nodes?

Tags: cluster-computing, mqtt, mqtt-vernemq

i am a new user in MQTT,
 and would to create a vernemq cluster of three nodes , how can i do this ? (with mosquitto client) please .
I have try to do it with the bridge in two distinct VM on ubuntu 18 but i haven't succes .

Answer (score 2):

First you need to have 3 running VerneMQ nodes. Then you'll join one node to the other like this:

`vmq-admin cluster join discovery-node=<OtherClusterNode>`

Then you check the cluster state (you should see a 2 node cluster):

`vmq-admin cluster show`

Then you repeat the first command and join the 3rd node to the cluster (the discovery-node can be any node in the existing cluster).

Note: your VerneMQ nodes need to be configured correctly, namely with regard to configured listeners and ports. See here: 
https://vernemq.com/docs/clustering/communication.html

If you use cloud VMs/Docker or similar, make sure you configure access accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer ,i tried to create more of node on the same computer like :

vernemq.config

 $ nodename = VerneMQ@192.168.0.1
 $ nodename = VerneMQ2@192.168.0.2 
 $ nodename = VerneMQ3@192.168.0.3 
 $ nodename = VerneMQ4@192.168.0.4 

but i had this error

$ vernemq failed to start within 15 
$ see the output of 'vernemq console' for more 
$ If you want to wait longer, set the environment 
$ WAIT_FOR_ERLANG to the number of seconds to wait.

Comment: This should be part of the documentation of the VerneMQ clustering guide. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks, @thepanuto. Added some documentation here as requested: https://docs.vernemq.com/misc/clustering-during-development

Answer (score 2):

You need to take care of a couple things if you want to run multiple VerneMQ instances on the same machine. There is a `make` option that let's you build multiple releases, as a commodity. This will prepare 3 correctly configured vernemq.conf files, with different ports for the MQTT listeners etc.

`➜  default git:(master) ✗ make dev1 dev2 dev3`

This will prepare different vernemq.conf files in the respective release builds. (look at them in the `_build` directory after having built the releases.)

You can then start the respective broker instances in 3 terminal windows.
Hope this helps.

EDIT: can't comment yet, so had to add this as an answer.

Comment: You can always edit your original answer to add clarification